# How to use my iPhone 7 Plus as a WiFi Adapter for my Windows 10 desktop pc?

Tags: iphone, wifi, usb

so I've been wanting to find out how to use my iPhone as a WiFi adapter for my PC, through my lightning USB cable. Since my current WiFi adapter for my PC is garbage, I want to temporarily use my phone as an adapter since it's speeds are way more faster.

I'm on a normal broadband wireless internet connection, and I don't want answers involving cellular data and 4G, 5G mobile data hotspots etc

Thanks a ton!

Comment: I honestly don't think you can use your iPhone as a WiFi adapter.  Hotspots yes.  But using it to replace your WiFi adapter...  that's really not what the phone is designed for.   I could be wrong here, but this doesn't seem like a 'normal' thing.

Comment: Does this help? https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/share-your-internet-connection-iph45447ca6/ios

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share iPhone WIFI with computer over USB?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31182/share-iphone-wifi-with-computer-over-usb)